# How to create a 3 column (ul, li) header that (responsive) collapse one below another?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**The fiddle is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/734os9yf/)**

I have a very odd HTML structure old website.
Client is asking me to make it responsive.

I need this website need to behave responsive from the breaking point 768px.

I've changed the HTML structure bit as follow:

```
<div id="tm_container">
    <div id="backtotop"></div>
    <div class="tm_header_file">
        <div class="social_bar">
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="top-header">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="#"><li>
                    <li><img src="#"><li>
                    <li><img src="#"><li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div class="tm_menu_desktop">
        <!-- desktop navigation -->
    </div>

    <div class="tm_menu_mobile">
        <!-- mobile navigation -->
    </div>

    <div class="tm_content">
        <!-- Contents -->
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="tm_footer">
        <!-- Footer code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Already I have these CSS codes in `style.css`

```
.top-header ul li { float: left; width: 13.2%; padding: 21px 4px 0;}
.top-header ul li:first-child { width: 12.75%; padding: 0;}
.top-header ul li:last-child { width: 73.1%; padding: 0;}
.top-header ul li a img { width: 100%;}
```

and then I created the media query as follow in `responsive.css`:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { /*  responsive - starts from iPad portrait view */      
        #tm_container { padding: 0 1%;}
        .tm_menu_desktop { display: none;}
        .tm_header_file { width: 100%; }
        .tm_content { display: inline-block; width: 100%; }
        .top-header ul li, .top-header ul li:first-child { width : auto;}
        .top-header ul li a img { width : 132px; }
        .top-header ul li:last-child { display: none; } 
    }
```

After I added the above code in `responsive.css` the body content and footer are ok. those are responsive now.

what I want to achieve :

1. `3rd li` in the `top-header` class should be disappear - done
2. `2nd and 1st` li in the `top-header` class should be `centered` in the same line during the collapse in 768 breaking point - NOT done
3. `2nd li` should be go below to the 3rd li in the `top-header` class and should be both centered - NOT done

for now `1st & 2nd` li are in the left side/floting left next to each other. how can I get those centered?
And how about 3rd point?

**The fiddle is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/734os9yf/)**

Comment: r u looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/734os9yf/1/

Comment: wwuu.. yeah.. exactly that's what.. float : none and margin : 0 auto did the trick.. could you make it as answer? I'll accept and upvote you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comment above, Here is the answer. Just remove `float` property from the li and apply some small width for `ul` property and use `margin:0px auto` to make it center.

```
 .top-header ul{width:100px; margin:0px auto;}
 .top-header ul li{float:none;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/734os9yf/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.top-header ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;  text-align: center;}
.top-header ul li { float: left; width: 13.2%; padding: 21px 4px 0;}
.top-header ul li:first-child { width: 12.75%; padding: 0;}
.top-header ul li:last-child { width: 73.1%; padding: 0;}
.top-header ul li a img { width: 100%;}

@media (max-width: 768px) { /*  responsive - starts from iPad portrait view */      
        #tm_container { padding: 0 1%;}
        .tm_menu_desktop { display: none;}
        .tm_header_file { width: 100%; }
        .tm_content { display: inline-block; width: 100%; }
        .top-header ul li, .top-header ul li:first-child { width : 100%;}
        .top-header ul li a img { width : 132px; }
        .top-header ul li:last-child { display: none; } 
    }
```

```html
<div id="tm_container">
 <div id="backtotop"></div>
 <div class="tm_header_file">
  <div class="social_bar">
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   <div class="top-header">
    <ul>
     <li><img src="http://asiamediaglobal.net/riffaz/athavaneng-for-live-test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/language_selection.png"></li>
     <li><img src="http://asiamediaglobal.net/riffaz/athavaneng-for-live-test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/language_selection.png"></li>
     <li><img src="http://asiamediaglobal.net/riffaz/athavaneng-for-live-test/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/language_selection.png"></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 
 <div class="tm_menu_desktop">
  <!-- desktop navigation -->
 </div>
 
 <div class="tm_menu_mobile">
  <!-- mobile navigation -->
 </div>
 
 <div class="tm_content">
  <!-- Contents -->
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 
 <div class="tm_footer">
  <!-- Footer code -->
 </div>
</div>
```